# Convert datetime string to local datetime

Tags: node.js, datetime

I have an API that returns a datetime string in this format `2020-02-15T06:51:00.000Z` in the Eastern US timezone.

I am trying to convert it to my local timezone and I have tried simply passing it into a new date constructor like this `new Date('2020-02-15T06:51:00.000Z')` with no success.

How can I convert it to my local timezone?

Comment: use moment.js npm package

Comment: Thats for formatting dates not converting timezones

Comment: Yes, True. But there is a resque https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/

Comment: Moment timezone is another package

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, I've tried this `moment.tz(date, 'Europe/London').format()` where `date` is my date `2020-02-15T06:51:00.000Z` and it just outputs `2020-02-15T06:51:00Z`

Answer (score 0):

You could try like:

`new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York"})`

Comment: You can read details about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141762/how-to-initialize-a-javascript-date-to-a-particular-time-zone)

Comment: I still dont see how that can help